# How do you query a MySQL table columns highest entry and store it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

How do you query a MySQL table columns highest entry and store it in a variable. Here is what I have but it is not working.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;
```

#### Update:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "123", "123");
mysql_select_db("123");
$currentip='123.456.789';
$query = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";
$date = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $date;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out, when you try to echo `$result` you are only echoing the *resource* since that is what [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns.

If you want to echo the column, try:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['date'];
}
```

Or you could use [`mysql_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) which return the return value into a string.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";
$date = mysql_result($result, 0);  
echo $date;
```

Either should work, it hasn't been tested or compiled.

#### In regards to your updated code:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "123", "123");
mysql_select_db("123");
$currentip='123.456.789';
$query = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";
$result = mysql_query($query); // <--you forgot this line.
$date = mysql_result($result, 0); // <--now $result has a valid resource.
echo $date;
?>
```

I would also strongly suggest that since you are a new PHP programmer, get into the habit of incorporating some form of error-handling/checking, such as

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "123", "123");
if (!$db) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
...
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Could not perform query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Performing error-checks from the start of your programming experience is really good practice and will better suit you for the long-run.

Comment: Thanks. Im climbing this cliff and it only gets higher. 

ps. new user.

Comment: Every new user experiences problems, at least you know a good resource to come search for answers, and if none are found, ask questions.

Comment: mysql_result method still returns error.Wrong parameter count for mysql_result()

Comment: I had edited the answer, did you supply a row number, since it should be the first row, I used `0`. Also, have you opened up a connection to the database, using `mysql_connect`? If not, let me know and I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: i have not + there is too much going on right now. Hard to focus.

Comment: yep. connection is there, everything is right. Row 0 is the first row? IDK. I dont want bugs in this part of the application.

Comment: Yeah, rows start at index `0`. As long as you have a connection, you should be good to go.

Comment: <?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "123", "123");
mysql_select_db("123");
$currentip='123.456.789';
$query = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";
$date = mysql_result($result, 0);  
echo $date;
?>

What is wrong here. It returns error mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @user315819, inside `mysql_result` you need to supply a valid MySQL resource. Resources are given by calling `mysql_query` which you are not. See my above edit for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

use [max()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) in your query

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(column_name) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Max() will work with group by clause

```
"SELECT MAX(date) AS mdate FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip' GROUP BY ips";
```

Comment: use MAX(date) AS mdate, and then echo $fetchdata['mdate']

Answer (score 0):

```
 $myQuery = "SELECT MAX(date) FROM Records WHERE ips='$currentip'";

 $result = mysql_query($myQuery,$connection);

 $mydate= mysql_fetch_row($result);

 echo $mydate[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to read the manual chapter for the [MySQL Functions](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php). Composing a program by picking random functions from third-party code and trying to guess how they work can only lead to a nervous breakdown.

To sum up:

- mysql_query() executes a query and returns a resource ID
- You use such resource ID to fetch rows with any of the mysql_fetch_*() functions

I particularly like mysql_fetch_assoc():

```
<?php
# ...
if( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource_id) ){
    echo $row['MAX(date)'];
}
?>
```

I'd also recommend some tutorial about basic SQL. For instance, you can define aliases to make results easier to handle:

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date FROM ...
echo $row['max_date'];
```

Last but not least, if you put your site online before reading about SQL Injection please let us know so we can hack it ;-) (Hint: http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)